# My navigation disappears when the browser is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, this is a site that i'm currently working on and everything is fine except this: 
As i got warned by one of the guys reviewing my current code, my menu/navigation disappears after being open and closed in its media-querie state, and resized back to monitor-width.

**Simplified - follow these steps to see the problem:** 
 
Open the code snippet (i would suggest CodePen since the result is shown properly in it) and briefly admire my design. Tthat's it, thank you for your help. Just kidding, next step: resize the browser to the mentioned size (width 480px or less) so that you see the hamburger menu icon on top right, open the menu clicking on the icon, close it, and than change the browser back to full screen size! Do you see the navigation bar on the left?! 
**What am i missing here?** I suppose that it should be a few more lines of JavaScript for some after state (just started learning JS so i dont know), but please look into it and teach me about possible solution(s). 
And yes i know, it shouldn't affect any of those mobile users that i'm targeting with my media-queries 'cause nobody will resize it like that and barely anyone will see this, BUT...first thing - i want to make it perfect, and second - if there is something i missed or did wrong i want to hear about it and learn how to fix it/make it right. 
Here is the CodePen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxmMrJ 
And here is the code snippet:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("menu");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } 
    else {
        x.style.display =  "block";
    }
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    
    .networks, .sidenav, .image-row, .foot1, .foot3 {
    display: none;
    }
    
    body {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    }
    
    .page-wrap {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .logo {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    }
    
    .logoImg {
    width: 200%;
    }
    
    .menuIcon {
 display: inline-block;
    float: right;
 width: 10%;
    margin-top: 6%;
 margin-right: 5.5%;
    border: none;
    z-index: 3;
    }

    .navButton {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    border: none;
    z-index: 3;
    }
    
    .navButton:focus {
    outline: none;
    }
    
    #menu {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    padding-bottom: 2.5%;
    z-index: 3;
    }
    
    .main {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 7.5%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .textbox {
 display: block;
    width: 95%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    text-align: justify;
    }
    
    .myPhoto {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .foot2 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: #324B64;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, 
                   initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
    
    <title>Luka Novak</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="page-wrap">
        
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            
        </div>
        <div class="networks">
            <a href="#"><img src="facebook-symbol.svg" class="socialnet" alt="facebook"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="instagram-symbol.svg" class="socialnet" alt="instagram"></a>
        </div>
            <div class="menuIcon">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="navButton">
                <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gray-toolbar/512/menu-512.png" 
                     alt="menu" 
                     class="iconImg">
            </button>
            </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sidenav col-5" id="menu">
        <a href="#" class="navlink">about us</a>
        <a href="#" class="navlink">services</a>
        <a href="#" class="navlink">contact</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="main col-18">
        
        <article class="textbox">
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
        </article>
        
        <div class="image-row">
            <div class="image1">
            
            </div>
                
            <div class="image2">
                    
            </div>
                
            <div class="image3">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="footer col-24">
        <p class="foot1">Some info</p>
        <p class="foot2">design by me</p>
        <p class="foot3">More info</p>
    </div>
    
</div>
    
</body>    

</html>
```

Comment: Your nav disappears after closing it on mobile and then resizing to desktop because the JavaScript puts in the inline css style of `display: none;` after closing the menu. One quick way to fix this would be to add in a media query and put `display: block !important;` on the `.sidenav` div.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but unfortunately i have only bad news - not acceptable, because !important even overrides all other styles and JS so the menu stays visible over my text at all times (no opening or closing needed, its always opened that way)

Comment: Well my solution isn't the most ideal solution which is why I put it in a comment but I also said to put it in a media query targeting the width that's after the mobile menu so that on mobile when the mobile menu is visible the `display: block !important` doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to do this with a CSS class that it only changed in your mobile media query.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KRmYVR

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mobileshow {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

JS

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("menu");
  if(x.classList.contains("mobileshow")) {
    x.classList.remove("mobileshow");
  }
  else {
    x.classList.add("mobileshow");
  }
}
```

Comment: I get what you're doing but i dont see that class (".mobileshow") anywhere in html, shouldnt it be there too? Sorry if its a stupid question, as for my knowledge every class noted in css should be "called" from html...please dont tell me im wrong?

Comment: The javascript adds it to the HTML. When you click your menu button from your mobile view is adds the `.mobileshow` class to the `#menu` element. If it sees that it already has that class, then it removes it (which effectively hides the sidenav)

Comment: You're right, very simple. Dont know how did i miss that, sorry! But there is another problem, your solution keeps the sidenav visible after browser width change, but that "overlaying" effect of my menu is removed and ofc i want to have it just like it was...you get what i think - when i click the hamburger, the navigation menu should show up overlaying other site elements (textbox in this case) and not push them down. What can i do about that?

Comment: You want the mobile navigation to overlap the main body section of the page? The codepen you provided doesn't seem to do that. You could use absolute positioning on the mobileshow class though to achieve that.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Forgot to update codepen when i set menu's position to absolute. Sorry! Tends to happen when i code in Brackets, not CodePen so much... Anyway everything's perfect now, thank you very much for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Those attributes of "element.style" can only be set a value rather than get their value(you can run "console.log(x.style.display)" to prove it). if you must to get styles of an element, try "[getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)"
2. Usually, I would hide an element by add a class, and show it by remove that class

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.some-element')

function hideElement() {
  if (!el.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    el.classList.add('hidden')
  }
}

function showElement() {
  if (el.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    el.classList.remove('hidden')
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
/* you can try this, if you don't want that element to really disappear
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="some-element"></div>
```

PS: My English is poor, hope you could understand it :)

Comment: I had no problems understanding your english, rather this JS that i'm still very new with, haha... seems that im misplacing something so it makes me wonder - would i bother too much if asking you to "repair" my codepen (link in the main question) and send it here as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that setting `x.style.display = "none";` in the js ignores the stylesheet and overrides it. This means that even if you are in the mobile break point, opening and closing the menu overrides the element `display` and this change remains even if you return to a desktop breakpoint. However, if you opened the menu once again before changing the screensize, the menu would stay visible.

The solution to this is to let the stylesheet do the work.

```css
/* Menu is visible by default */
#menu {
    display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    
    /* Hides the menu by default on smaller screen sizes */
    #menu {
        display: none;
    }

    /* Shows the menu when the visible class is toggled */
    #menu.visible {
        display: block;
    }

}
```

And then all that is needed is the js to toggle the visible class.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("menu");
    x.classList.toggle('visible');
}
```

The benefit of this is that js is not overriding the display property of the element, but is toggling a class that only affects the declarations within the media query. Toggling this will change the visibility of the element while the screen size is small, but returns to normal as soon as the browser window is resized.